# Typescript: How to convert map of 'typeof class' to map of class instances

Tags: typescript

I have an object map as follows:

```typescript
const obj: {
    AddRowOperation: typeof RowOperations.AddRowOperation;
    DeleteRowOperation: typeof RowOperations.DeleteRowOperation;
    FilterRowsOperation: typeof RowOperations.FilterRowsOperation;
    ... 25 more ...;
    ResetRowStatusOperation: typeof RowOperations.ResetRowStatusOperation;
}
```

I want to map this object to instances of each class. So the type should be:

```typescript
const obj: {
    AddRowOperation: RowOperations.AddRowOperation;
    DeleteRowOperation: RowOperations.DeleteRowOperation;
    FilterRowsOperation: RowOperations.FilterRowsOperation;
    ... 25 more ...;
    ResetRowStatusOperation: RowOperations.ResetRowStatusOperation;
}
```

I have tried a lot of options, but the type always ends up being unioned like:

```typescript
const obj: {
    AddRowOperation: (RowOperations.AddRowOperation | RowOperations.DeleteRowOperation | ...);
    // etc...
}
```

I would have thought this was a simple scenario. It would be great to dynamically instantiate the classes rather than manually typing each one out.

Can this be done while keeping typescript happy? The classes do not share a common interface.

**Edit**

Solution proposed by jaclz:

```typescript
type InstanceTypeProps<T extends Record<keyof T, new (...args: any) => any>> = { [K in keyof T]: InstanceType<T[K]> };

class A {}
class B {}
class C {}

const obj = { A, B, C }

type mapOfInstances = InstanceTypeProps<typeof obj>
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgZ2AQzgYwgFXBACgJwHswEAeTKCAD2AjgBMEoAlCNQ-e0gawhEIBmUTABoocCAHcoACgB0C5PgDmCAFxRUIAJRQAvAD5NcEAaN6oAbygBtANJQAlnCi9%20QzAF0N8JKgzYkOT2nkYAvgDcALAAULFoADbICEwAglZh8UkpUABCGVnJTADCBXEx7IjAUIQARgBW%20lZQqWK5YqWZ5aCQUAC2yGAA8gK%20KOgQTBZj-lg4BMRkPRCCNQ0GsUA)

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] that can be pasted into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w6XZ0m) to demonstrate the issue you're seeing?  I could suggest something like `InstanceTypeProps` from the link, but without a testable example it's hard to tell.  If that works for you I could potentially come up with my own example code for the answer, but ideally it would be in the question itself.

Comment: @jcalz yep, that's done the trick. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgZ2AQzgYwgFXBACgJwHswEAeTKCAD2AjgBMEoAlCNQ-e0gawhEIBmUTABoocCAHcoACgB0C5PgDmCAFxRUIAJRQAvAD5NcEAaN6oAbygBtANJQAlnCi9+QzAF0N8JKgzYkOT2nkYAvgDcALAAULFoADbICEwAglZh8UkpUABCGVnJTADCBXEx7IjAUIQARgBW+lZQqWK5YqWZ5aCQUAC2yGAA8gK+KOgQTBZj-lg4BMRkPRCCNQ0GsUA

Comment: post an answer I can upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `typeof obj` where each property is transformed via [`InstanceType<T>`, a utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) which uses [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to turn a [construct signature type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) into that of the instances it constructs.  Let's call this mapped type `InstanceTypeProps<T>`.  You could write it like this:

```
type InstanceTypeProps<T extends Record<keyof T, new (...args: any) => any>> =
    { [K in keyof T]: InstanceType<T[K]> };
```

We're just applying `InstanceType` to each property `T[K]`.  The only extra detail is that we have to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to a type where each property is a construct signature.  That looks like `Record<keyof T, new (...args: any) => any>`, meaning an object whose keys are whatever keys we want (it's really no constraint on the keys to say that `T extends Record<keyof T, ...>`) and whose values are assignable to `new (...args:any) => any`, a construct signature.

Let's make sure it works:

```
type MapOfInstances = InstanceTypeProps<typeof obj>;
/* type MapOfInstances = {
    AddRowOperation: RowOperations.AddRowOperation;
    DeleteRowOperation: RowOperations.DeleteRowOperation;
    FilterRowsOperation: RowOperations.FilterRowsOperation;
    //... 25 more ...;
    ResetRowStatusOperation: RowOperations.ResetRowStatusOperation;
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgZ2AQzgYwgFXBACgJwHswEAeTKCAD2AjgBMEoAlCNQ-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-r5nLbrIDqts8pFfY7LK9sqHivbKIHJzOptySOVZU7042nJNmsX44tLetCltPz+joUs+DoY9S4Dq5HKM557dYavfMjUHLjyAA)